# Changing the Position of DIV AP tags in Dreamweaver

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

When I change the position from absolute to relative or anything it completely screws up everything. Sending images everywhere on the layout. I dont know what to do. Please help =[[ Because as it stands now, when a browser is mazimized the text looks off as far as placement on the layout depending on the computer i am testing it on. Website - www.byteknightrepair.com

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org      /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>-ByteKnight Repair-</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="site_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
</style>
<link href="site_layout_content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#testimonials {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:115px;
z-index:1;
left: 220px;
top: 563px;
float: right;
}
body,td,th {
color: #999;
}
#housecalls {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:105px;
z-index:2;
left: 504px;
top: 557px;
}
#WhatWeDo {
position:;
width:379px;
height:46px;
z-index:3;
left: 201px;
top: 222px;
}
</style>
<link href="site_layout_whatwedo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#Description {
position:absolute;
width:326px;
height:73px;
z-index:4;
left: 219px;
top: 289px;
}
#news {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:115px;
z-index:5;
left: 804px;
top: 556px;
}
#apDiv6 {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:115px;
z-index:6;
left: 721px;
top: 390px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Waoh, well, my first suggestion would be to start anew and position everything correctly. The text on your page is flying everywhere because they're not properly contained and are just manually positioned across the screen, absolutely positioned relative to the screen you were using at the time, thus why they are flying everywhere (not everybody has the same screen size). Here are a few things you can do to do a quick fix:

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}

#description {
    padding:30px;
    position:absolute;
    width:326px;
}
```

Later remove your "What we do" div and just incase it inside your "description" div, like so:

```
<div id="Description">
<h2>What we do</h2>
<p>ByteKnight Repair is a local, San Fernando Valley based computer repair and servicing company that services both PC desktops and laptops of all brands.</p></div>
```

That should stop that piece of text from floating around when the screen is resized.

Now on to your Prices page.

First, format your **#apDiv5** id to this:

```
#apDiv5 {
    color:#ccc;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    position:absolute;
    width:255px;
}
```

And then, fix the td encasing that that div, placing the image "below" the content, like so:

```
<td colspan="3" rowspan="4">
        <div id="apDiv5">
          <p>The squire tune-up includes: </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Clear Cache</li>
            <li>Clear Pagefiles</li>
            <li>Virus Scan</li>
            <li>Virus Removal</li>
            <li>Spyware Scan</li>
            <li>Spyware Removal</li>
            <li>Registry Cleaning</li>
            <li>Registry Defragmentation</li>
            <li>Hard Drive Test</li>
            <li>RAM Test</li>
            <li>CPU Thermal Test</li>
            <li>Configure Windows Updates</li>
            <li>Remove Unneeded Startup Programs</li>
          </ul>
      </div><img width="260" height="350" src="images/prices_28.jpg" alt="">
</td>
```

Also, on your "Knightly Tune-up" section, change the **#apDiv4** id on that div to **#apDiv5**.

That should fix most of your alignment problems, although i highly suggest starting from scratch, you can easily position such design with tables alone. Also, try to make all this changes through the regular editor and not through the visual editor.

As always, if it works it works, no matter how it is set up. Good luck.